# Select if the record is updated using MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am and new to MySQL and learning it. I don't know if there is way to Select the records which are updated. For example, if I have a Student database

```
ID | Name |    DOB   | Total-Marks |
------------------------------------- 
01 |  ABC | 08-22-91 |   499       |
02 |  DEF | 07-14-91 |    407      |
03 |  GHI | 01-31-90 |    378      |
```

If there was some updates happened in the Total-Marks field, I need to select only the updated records. Can anybody tell me, how can I do this. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How about having a History table and a Trigger which populates the History table with changes in main table.

Comment: Alternatively, MySQL's timestamp type can be [automatically initialised when a row is created, and updated with the current time when an update is made to the row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html), so you can easily ask "what's changed since X date/time?" It might help to explain a little more about what you need, how the records get updated, etc.

Comment: You can add a column named "updated_at" with type of Timestamp, and use Now() when you use update command. Then use this column to find when each row is updated

Comment: I am not having access to do changes to the table existing.

Comment: If you don't have access to change the database, then as far as I can see, there's no way of telling when records have been updated. (Why don't you have access to change the table? Expecting you to implement features like this without the ability to change the structure of the database seems a bit crazy...)

Comment: Are you able to create _new_ tables?

Comment: Thanks Matt. I will discuss about changing the database. Since I am new to sql wanted to make sure that if there is any other way too. Thank you everybody in quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a column to the table `last_updated` using the TIMESTAMP data type. That data type has a special behavior that by default, it updates to the current date & time automatically when you update the row. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html for details on this.

So you would add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD COLUMN last_updated TIMESTAMP 
  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Then as you INSERT/UPDATE to that table, just ignore the column. I.e. don't specify a value for the column, and the default takes over and provides the value.

Then you can query for all records updated since a given date:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE last_updated > '2014-11-12 5:21:00';
```

---

Re your comment:

In general, you can query for rows based on values found in columns of the rows. There is no "last updated" metadata that you can query. If you cannot add a column, you can only query based on the columns you have so far.

One strategy in this case would be to query on the ID column. If you keep track somewhere else of the last ID you read, then you can query for new rows:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID > $last_id_you_read
```

But this only finds *new* rows, not rows that were changed since the last time you read them. There is no way to detect this if you cannot change the table or create a trigger or another table.

Comment: Thanks Bill. How can this be approached, if I am not having access to the existing table.